# Clean list from data.frame without names from the line numbers

Tags: r

Not sure how to phrase my question concisely, but here goes.

Context: I want to make a json file with multiple levels from a dataframe, so therefore I first construct a nested list from my dataframe.

```
# load libraries
library(RJSONIO)

# make data
dt <- data.frame(var1 = 1:4, var2 = c("a", "b", "c", "d"), var3 = c("foo", "bar", "foobar", "foobaz"), var4 = c(100, 200, 300, 400))

# make nested list
ll <- apply(dt, 1, function(x) list(id = x[['var1']], props = list(name = x[['var2']], altName = x[['var3']], height = x[['var4']])))

# output to JSON and print
js <- toJSON(ll); cat(js)

# output
[
 {
 "id": "1",
"props": {
 "name": "a",
"altName": "foo",
"height": "100" 
} 
},
...
```

Everything works as expected. But then I want to filter on the dataframe and for some reason R nests my initial list into an object named with the line number

```
# make nested list of dataframe from before but now filter on var1
dt <- dt[dt$var1 %% 2 == 0, ]
ll <- apply(dt, 1, function(x) list(id = x[['var1']], props = list(name = x[['var2']], altName = x[['var3']], height = x[['var4']])))

# output to JSON and print
js <- toJSON(ll); cat(js)

# output
 {
 "2": {
   "id": "1",
  "props": {
   "name": "a",
   "altName": "foo",
   "height": "100" 
  }
 } 
},
...
```

Now, with `unname()` I can remove the names 2 and 4, but why is this happening in the first place and is there a way to prevent the initial naming of the lists? As always, any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically what happens is that you have a data.frame that hasn't been subset, it has a special row-name property that just assigns a unique number to each row. But when you subset, that special value is disrupted. Notice here how it keeps the original index of 2 and 4

```
dt[dt$var1 %% 2 == 0, ]
#   var1 var2   var3 var4
# 2    2    b    bar  200
# 4    4    d foobaz  400
```

These are resulting in names in your output. You can get rid of those row names as you have done with `unname()`. Again, this doesn't happen on the fill data.frame because they have a "magic" value that indicates to special names for the rows in order to save memory space.

But it can also be dangerous to run `apply` in a data.frame with all the data type conversion that can happen. Another possible strategy is to use a few tidyverse libraries

```
library(tidyverse) # dplur, purrr, tidyr
library(jsonlite)
dt %>% 
  rename(id=var1, name=var2, altName=var3, height=var4) %>% 
  nest(-id, .key="props") %>% 
  mutate(props=map(props, unbox)) %>% 
  toJSON()
```

Comment: Related/follow up question: making a new dataframe by calling `as.data.frame()` after filtering doesn't solve this issue, is there a reason why? Also: thanks for the additional tips on preventing accidental type conversion

Comment: Did you call as.data.frame on something that was already a data.frame? I wouldn’t expect that to do anything at all. Not sure what you were expecting.

Comment: I did call it on the subset dataframe after filtering. I kind of expected that it would make a 'new' dataframe like you described with the special row number values.